# Streams in Java, can't figure this code out

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've found the following code snippet:

```
Function<Integer, Predicate<Integer>> smallerThan = x -> y -> y < x;
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 23, 4, 5645,
    6, 1223, 44453, 60182, 2836, 23993, 1);

List<Integer> list2 = l.stream()
    .filter(smallerThan.apply(l.get(0)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list2);
```

As output I receive:

```
[4, 1]
```

How does the `smallerThan` function in this example work, considering that we only pass one parameter `smallerThan.apply(l.get(0))`?

Comment: `smallerThan` is a function that returns a function.

Comment: You can re-write `smallerThan` like this: `x -> (y -> (y < x))`

Comment: See [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`smallerThan` is a `Function` that accepts a single `Integer` and returns a `Predicate<Integer>` (a `Predicate<Integer>` is a function that accepts a single `Integer` and returns a `boolean`).

`smallerThan.apply(l.get(0))` returns a `Predicate<Integer>` that looks like this:

```
y -> y < l.get(0)
```

i.e. it returns `true` if the input passed to it is smaller than `l.get(0)`.

When you pass that `Predicate` to `filter`, your `Stream` pipeline keeps only the elements smaller than `l.get(0)`.

Your pipeline can be re-written as:

```
List<Integer> list2 = l.stream()
    .filter(y -> y < l.get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since `l.get(0)` is `5`, your pipeline returns all the elements of the original list smaller than `5`.

Answer (score 13):

That is called "currying" and it was possible before Java 8 too via anonymous classes for example, but it was much more verbose. Ultimately, it's a `Function` that returns a `Function` and while not that spread in Java (yet), in other functional languages it is used quite heavily.

Answer (score 8):

The function `smallerThan` accepts a number and returns a `Predicate` object, in which case we apply this predicate to every element of the stream.

So, `l.get(0)` will retrieve the first value of the list `l` which is `(5)`, we then pass it to the `smallerThan` function and this function returns a predicate with the criteria `y -> y < x;` which reads as *"given a number, return true if it is less than 5"*  hence output is `[4, 1]`